# Remove duplicates in array which numbers are in string format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have snippet like how to remove duplicates from and array. I tried using filter method but its working with only numbers, But my array contains numbers in string format. So i am in confusion how to solve it.

```
// javascript

// output = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

const arr1 = [1,2,"1",3,2,4,"3",5,6,7,6,"5"];

const result = arr1.filter((item, index) => arr1.indexOf(item) === index)

//console.log(result);

// my result 

// [1, 2, "1", 3, 4, "3", 5, 6, 7, "5"]

// But output should be = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: What a bad format! How bad the format is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arr = [1,2,"1",3,2,4,"3",5,6,7,6,"5"];

const tempArr = arr.map(val => Number(val));

const result = Array.from(new Set(tempArr));

console.log(result) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just parse the strings as a number with `parseInt(item)` and then compare those. This code will parse strings as Int and then filter those.

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,"1",3,2,4,"3",5,6,7,6,"5"];

arr1 = arr1.map(m => parseInt(m));

const result = arr1.filter((item, index) => arr1.indexOf(item) === index)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Seems more simple and more elegant

Comment: Have you upvote my previous answers,please? It seems someone has upvote many of my previous answer,and this will be detected by stackoverflow,it's a bad behavior.Please do not do that,thank you very much

Comment: i removed 1 number then i am getting output like this : [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; 1 number in the string should be number righ? so the out put should be [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] after removing 1 number. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Number()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert string to number and then filter it,below is a reference for you

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,"1",3,2,4,"3",5,6,7,6,"5"];

const filterArr = (data) =>{
  data = data.filter((e, i) => data.indexOf(Number(e)) === i)
  return data
}

console.log(filterArr(arr1))
```

Comment: i removed 1 number then i am getting output like this : [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; 1 number in the string should be number righ? so the out put should be [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] after removing 1 number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,"1",3,2,4,"3",5,6,7,6,"5"];

const result = [...new Set(arr1.map(Number))]

console.log(result);
```

What this does is:

- convert everything to a number (`map(Number)`)
- turn an array into a `Set` (means no duplicates)
- convert that set back into an array with `[...]`